# Get translated country name from a 2 digit country code in Symfony2/Twig?

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-forms

I'm using the Symfony2 [country Field Type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/country.html), it works well and country names are translated. I am storing the two-digit country code in the column `country` of my entity.

**How can I display the full, translated country name?** This is how I added the field to the form:

```
$builder
    ->add('country', 'country', array(
        'label' => 'Paese', 'preferred_choices' => array('IT')
    ));
```

And then in my controller:

```
$user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AcmeHelloBundle:User');
$countryCode = $user->getCountry();
$countryName = null; // Get translated country name from code
```

Or in my twig template:

```
{# Output the country code and name #}
{{ user.country }}

{# translated country name from code #}
```

Answer (score 21):

I'm not sure if you still need... but it might help someone else. this can be done through a twig extension easily (this code is based on @tomaszsobczak's answer )

```
<?php
    // src/Acme/DemoBundle/Twig/CountryExtension.php
    namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Twig;


    class CountryExtension extends \Twig_Extension {
        public function getFilters()
        {
            return array(
                new \Twig_SimpleFilter('country', array($this, 'countryFilter')),
            );
        }

        public function countryFilter($countryCode,$locale = "en"){
            $c = \Symfony\Component\Locale\Locale::getDisplayCountries($locale);

            return array_key_exists($countryCode, $c)
                ? $c[$countryCode]
                : $countryCode;
        }

        public function getName()
        {
            return 'country_extension';
        }
    }
```

And in your services.yml files

```
# src/Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/config/services.yml
services:
    acme.twig.country_extension:
        class: Acme\DemoBundle\Twig\CountryExtension
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

Usage example inside a twig file:

```
{{ 'US'|country(app.request.locale) }}
```

Comment: `\Symfony\Component\Locale\Locale` will be depricated in Symfony 3.0

Comment: I like this solution the best, just be carefull at public Function getFilter: Check your own version of symfony2 documentation for the proper return value (google for twig custom filter you'll find it fast)

Comment: Great simple solution. To fit with Sf 3.0, just change the `countryFilter` method this way:

`return Symfony\Component\Intl\Intl::getRegionBundle()->getCountryName($countryCode, $locale);
`

Answer (score 19):

As per @Rvanlaak's comment above, \Symfony\Component\Locale\Locale is now [deprecated](http://symfony.com/components/Locale). I think the most concise way to do this now is:

```
use Symfony\Component\Intl\Intl;

...

$country = Intl::getRegionBundle()->getCountryName($countryCode);
```

Answer (score 17):

Inspired by Hannoun Yassir answer, I use the Intl as in the country type field.
The code of twig extension is

```
<?php
namespace Tbl\SagaBundle\Twig;

use Symfony\Component\Intl\Intl;

class CountryExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFilter('countryName', array($this, 'countryName')),
        );
    }

    public function countryName($countryCode){
        return Intl::getRegionBundle()->getCountryName($countryCode);
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'country_extension';
    }
}
?>
```

Add twig extension in services.yml

```
# src/Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/config/services.yml
services:
    acme.twig.acme_extension:
        class: Acme\DemoBundle\Twig\CountryExtension
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

usage in the template (the country name will be display in locale by default (see Symfony/Component/Intl/ResourceBundle/RegionBundleInterface.php)

```
{{ user.countryCode|countryName }}
```

Many thanks Yassir, this version don't use locale deprecated since version 2.3 >> http://symfony.com/components/Locale

Comment: Unknown "countryName"

Answer (score 11):

Use SonanaIntlBundle, you could do something like this:

```
{{ 'FR' | country }} => France (if the current locale in request is 'fr')
{{ 'FR' | country('de') }} => Frankreich (force the locale)

{{ 'fr' | language }} => français (if the current locale in request is 'fr')
{{ 'fr' | language('en') }} => French (force the locale)

{{ 'fr' | locale }} => français (if the current locale in request is 'fr')
{{ 'fr' | locale('en') }} => French (force the locale)
```

[Read more about this](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/intl)

Comment: I'm not going to install a bundle just for this, but thanks. II think that the string name should already be in Symfony2.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the same component that Symfony is using for country Field Type

```
public function humanCountry() {
    $c = \Symfony\Component\Locale\Locale::getDisplayCountries('en');

    return array_key_exists($this->getCountry(), $c)
           ? $c[$this->getCountry()]
           : $this->getCountry();
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Well if you are using entities one option instead of doing twig filters is to create function for getting country name inside entity.

```
use Symfony\Component\Intl\Intl;

public function getCountryName() {
    return Intl::getRegionBundle()->getCountryName($this->getCountry());
}
```

So in twig later you can do

```
{{ user.countryName }}
```

Comment: Very nice! Thank you.

Comment: Unknown "countryName"

Answer (score 3):

For convenience purposes, if someone reads this some years later:

For twig 2 or later you can use

```
composer require twig/intl-extra
```

to make the filter *language_name* available. It also provides some options for configuration.

[See the doc.](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/language_name.html)