# Alphabetically sort a country list in a Symfony EntityType depending on the current locale

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

In order to get a HTML select tag of countries with only the countries that I want to appear, and having them translated through the **Symfony Intl Component** ([see doc here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/intl.html#country-names)) when the locale of my website changes, I've created a **Country** entity, with a custom getter `getTranslatedName()` to retrieve the translated name through its ISO code.

Then in my **ContactType** form type that needs to get the country list, I have a **EntityType** for the countries.

It's working fine, but the countries are not alphabetically sorted when you change the locale (default locale is English).

How can I achieve this ?

My custom getter :

```
/**
 * @return null|string
 */
public function getCountryName()
{
    if (null === $this->getIso()) {
        return $this->getName();
    }
    return Intl::getRegionBundle()->getCountryName($this->getIso());
}
```

My EntityType :

```
->add('country', EntityType::class, array(
    'class' => Country::class,
    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
            ->where('c.cc IS NOT NULL')
            ->orderBy('c.name', 'ASC');
    },
    'choice_label' => 'countryName',
    'choices_as_values' => true,
    'data' => $options['country'],
    'required' => true,
    'placeholder' => 'Choose from the list',
    'label'  => 'Country'
))
```

Comment: why don't you use [`CountryType` form field](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/country.html)?

Comment: Because I don't want to show ALL the countries, only a few of them. And I need to link each country to another entity representing its "human contact".

Comment: Your problem is, that you translate country name during rendering. Simplest solution for you is to [sort it via JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/278509).

Comment: Well, I'm not completely against updating my code architecture if it can be done server-side :) But I'll look into your solution.

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html

Comment: @eeXBee thanks, but can you clarify a bit more what you have in mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to load countries from database. You can override [`CountryType`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/country.html) and filter countries you want to select. Then store in your entities only ISO code. In templates you can show country name [using some filter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18559340).

```
namespace AppBundle\Form\Extension;

use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CountryType as BaseCountryType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\ChoiceList\ArrayChoiceList;
use Symfony\Component\Intl\Intl;

class CountryType extends BaseCountryType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function loadChoiceList($value = null)
    {
        if (null !== $this->choiceList) {
            return $this->choiceList;
        }

        $countryNames = array_filter(Intl::getRegionBundle()->getCountryNames(), function ($name, $isoCode) {
            return in_array($isoCode, ['US', 'CA', 'RU']);
        });

        return $this->choiceList = new ArrayChoiceList(array_flip($countryNames), $value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I'll test this ASAP! Looks nice.